# count the ocurances of a value in a list at js controller lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, map, count, aura-id, js-controller

Below is my list, and i would like to count the string and keep it in map

count==>["Vendor Master","Vendor Master","Customer Master","Customer Master","Customer Master","Customer Master","Material Master","Material Master","Material Master","Vendor Master"]

expected output:

Vendor Master:3,Customer Master:4,Material Master:3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep the count occurrence in the object, so you can set this object in component with object type attribute.

`<aura:attribute name="xyz" type= 'Object'/>`

```
let  count = {};
["Vendor Master","Vendor Master","Customer Master","Customer Master","Customer Master","Customer Master","Material Master","Material Master","Material Master","Vendor Master"].forEach(function(i) { count[i] = (count[i]||0) + 1;});
cmp.set('v.xyx',count);
console.log(count);
```

see the [codepen](https://codepen.io/sarveshgithub/pen/xxKyBeq?editors=0111) output.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet

```
const data = ["Vendor Master", "Vendor Master", "Customer Master", "Customer Master", "Customer Master", "Customer Master", "Material Master", "Material Master", "Material Master", "Vendor Master"];

function count(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((prev, curr) = > (prev[curr] = ++prev[curr] || 1, prev), {})
}
console.log(count(data))
```

Pass the array into the function `frequencies` and it will return you the map.

Output:

```
Object
Customer Master: 4
Material Master: 3
Vendor Master: 3
```